# python kafka consumer.poll msg.error dict object has no attribute error

Tags: python, kafka-python

I am trying to set up kafka message polling using consumer poll.
I can see loads of example code that uses message.error
e.g.

```
while True:
    try: 
        message = consumer.poll(10.0)

        if not message:
            time.sleep(120) # Sleep for 2 minutes

        if message.error():
            print(f"Consumer error: {message.error()}")
            continue

        print(f"Received message: {message.value().decode('utf-8')}")
    except:
        # Handle any exception here
```

But when I try these I get error ...
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'error' referring to the code line "if message.error():"

Is this a version issue or something ?
I don't understand why there are so many example code snippets with this code but it doesn't actually work ?
I assume message.value() will have a problem as well.

Note I am using kafka zookeeper NOT kafka confluent.

Copied code and ran it.

Answer (score 2):

The `consumer.poll()` method doesn't just return list of records. It returns a `dict` where keys are the partition, and values are the list of records in that partition ([source](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/_modules/kafka/consumer/group.html#KafkaConsumer.poll)). Your error arises because you're trying to loop over that dict, whereas your intention is to loop over only the records who are values in the dict.

A commonly used interface for handling the messages is to double-loop:

```
for topic_partition, records in messages.items():
    for record in records:
```

Comment: It's an odd duck - a dict with a key of, let's say `TopicPartition(topic='sometopic', partition=1)`, whose value is a list in which we have a named tuple.